# Laravel 5.1 Undefined variable: comments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to build a commenting system where users are able to leave comments behind on users projects posts.

I can save the and display the projects and on a specific project page(/projects/{id}) I have a form where users can leave comments behind. I am able to save the comments in the database but when I try to show the comments I get this error Undefined variable: comments (View: /var/www/resources/views/projects/show.blade.php).

My files:
Comment Model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
//comments table in database
protected $guarded = [];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// returns post of any comment
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','project_id');
}


public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
'user_id',
'title',
'tags',
'summary',
'file_name',
'published_at'
];
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

My User model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

public function Projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

}
```

My CommentController

```
 public function index()
{
    $comments = Comment::all();

    return view('projects.show', compact('comments'));
}

public function store()
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = $input['body'];
    $comment->on_projects = $input['project_id'];
    $comment->from_user = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->save();
    return redirect('projects/'.$input['project_id']);

}
```

My view

```
@section('content')
<a href="/projects">Terug naar alle projecten</a>
<h1>Werkje: {{ $project->title }}</h1>
<h3>Gemaakt door: <a href='/student/{{ $project->User->id }}'>{{ $project->User->name }}</a></h3>
<img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/uploads/projects/{{ $project->file_name }}">
<h5>Tags: {{$project->tags}}</h5>
<hr />
<h1>Reageer</h1>

@if (Auth::check())

    <article> <!--Add comment -->

        <br/>
        {!! Form::open() !!}
        {!! form::text('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

        <br/>

        {!! Form::Submit('Reageer', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('project_id', $project->id) !!}


        {!! Form::close() !!}
        <br/>

    </article>


    <article>

        @foreach ($comments as $comment)

            <article>

                <p>Body: {{ $comment->body }}</p>
                <p>{{ $comment->user->name }}</p>

            </article>


        @endforeach

    </article>
@else
    <p>Gelieve in te loggen om te kunnen reageren.</p>
@endif
```

My routes:

```
// Student routes REST methode
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::get('student/profile', 'StudentController@getProfile');

// add comment
Route::post('projects/{id}','CommentController@store');
// show comments
Route::get('projects/{id}','CommentController@index');

//Project routes REST methode
Route::post('projects/store', 'ProjectsController@store');
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');

// Authentication routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

// Password reset link request routes
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
```

I get this error now :
Undefined variable: project (View: /var/www/resources/views/projects/show.blade.php)

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: Laravel 5.1, thanks.

Comment: What happens if you put a `dd($comments)` right under `$comments = Comment::all();`?

Comment: unfortunately, nothing happens

Comment: That's weird... Are you sure that `public function index()` is being executed at all? If you comment out `//return view('projects.show', compact('comments'));` do you still see the view? Edit: It would be helpful if you posted your routes as well.

Comment: I commented out "return view('projects.show', compact('comments'));" and I can't see the view. And the same error is displayed.

Comment: Well, I wonder how you still get the same error when the line calling the view is commented out. Please post your URL that gets called and routes. Edit: I suspect that `show.blade.php` is being called somewhere else, not in your `index()` function.

Comment: My route works and the index() is accessed

Comment: And you still get this error `Undefined variable: comments (View: /var/www/resources/views/projects/show.blade.php)` if you comment out `return view('projects.show', compact('comments'));`?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I do.

Comment: post your routes please

Comment: Added routes to OP and new error occured

Comment: @Moussa Chaabar I didn't see a $project variable in your index method.

Comment: @Moussa Chaabar If  you want to add a route to resource controller, that you need to add It before resourse route.
Like here:
`Route::get('student/profile', 'StudentController@getProfile');
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');`

Comment: The $project comes from my ProjectController public function show($id)
    {
        $project = Project::all()->load("User");
        return view('projects.show', ['project' => Project::findOrFail($id)]);

    }

Answer (score 1):

The index() function in my CommentController is now empty.

I query the comments in my ProjectsController in my show{id} function

```
public function show($id)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $project = Project::all()->load("User");

    $project_comments = DB::table('comments')
        ->select('body', 'name')
        ->where('on_projects', '=', $id)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.from_user')
        ->get();

    return view('projects.show', ['project' => Project::findOrFail($id), 'comments' => $project_comments]);

}
```

And this is how I solved the conflicts in my routes

```
// add comment
Route::post('projects/{id}','CommentController@store');
// add project
Route::post('projects/store', 'ProjectsController@store');
//Project routes REST methode
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as per our chat, you had conflicts in your routes file as you were using a Resource for the projects and a Route for the projects in the same time. We sorted out the best way to load your comments for specific projects and everything works now, hope that helped :)

Comment: That maybe helps OP but not other users searching for a similar problem. Please post your solution.

Comment: is there any way to find the chat that was attached to this post? it was at least a half an hour discussion.